# ComboBox has extra space at the bottom

Tags: wpf, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a ComboBox that shows empty space below its values. See picture below.

The data in the view model is set in a button click handler. When I set the values in the initialization of the view model the ComboBox is fine. When I try to create a small example the ComboBox also has the expected size. It seems it depends somehow on the context where I set the values in the view model but I cannot figure out. I hope someone can give me a hint.

[image]

Code in the view model

```
Repositories.Clear();
Repositories.Add("One");
Repositories.Add("Two");
Repositories.Add("Three");
SelectedRepository = "One";
```

Code in XMAL

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="150" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          IsEnabled="{Binding CT.Connected}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CT.Repositories, 
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding CT.SelectedRepository}"/>
```

Comment: Control template would be a hint. http://www.wpftutorial.net/templates.html

Comment: Why do you have `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the `ItemsSource` binding?

Comment: I do not remember, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: What tool did you use to take your screen print? I like the ragged edges and drop shadow!

Comment: Snagit from Techsmith: https://www.techsmith.de/store/snagit?utm_source=google&utm_medium=g&utm_campaign=1538022855&utm_content=56328326062&utm_term=snagit&gclid=CjwKCAiA5qTfBRAoEiwAwQy-6dd7bflWdROv-EOeVZMSs3K9Ua-RxePsZrlmtmTxzYnWhcUsgU_diBoCHuAQAvD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

The `ItemsSource` you are binding to needs to be an `ObservableCollection`. The `ComboBox` will display the initial blank space if you bind the `ItemsSource` to any enumerable type that doesn't raise property changed when its items change.

Comment: Empty `ObservableCollection` doesn't prevent from extra empty space unfortunately.

Answer (score -1):

> When I try to create a small example the ComboBox has the expected size.

By that logic it maybe not the combobox, but the data which is in the list. Can you verify that there are not 8 items where the textual value to display is empty for the last four items or so?

### Or

Maybe a style is causing the extra space. Try removing the style from the combobox such as this

```
<ComboBox Style="{x:Null}"/>
```

and see if it has any effect to the visual result.

### Or

Also how about not setting the data and see if the drop down has the same size?

Comment: There seem to be quite a few questions and suggestions in your answer, and not so much in the way of answer.

Comment: @goobering Sadly the answer should be more concrete.  But in not seeing the code and only given a picture; my goal is to get the OP thinking and maybe provide insight to an answer. So far this is the only attempted answer....

Comment: Thanks for those hints. I've added C# code and XAML for that piece. It may be related to the fact that the ComboBox is set in a button click handler.